# SELECT DISTINCT not working after CASE statement

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to return the first message between two users, whether I sent that message or received it.  I've coded the below query which returns all the correct threads, but seems to ignore the DISTINCT clause - and I end up with multiple results with the same 'someid'.

How do I correct this query so that there will be no duplicate values returned in the resultant 'someid' column?

**Here's what I'm currently using:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senderid ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.id SEPARATOR ', ') END someid,   
            CASE WHEN $userid != senderid THEN senders.username ELSE GROUP_CONCAT(receivers.username SEPARATOR ', ') END somename,
            messages.body, 
            messages.time
    FROM messages 
    LEFT JOIN messages_recipients AS recipients ON messages.id = recipients.messageid
    LEFT JOIN users AS senders ON messages.senderid = senders.id
    LEFT JOIN users AS receivers ON recipients.userid = receivers.id
    WHERE recipients.userid = $userid
    OR messages.senderid = $userid
    GROUP BY messages.id
    ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

Comment: i think you will have to break into 2 queries, with the inner one performng the Distinct on SomeId ...

Comment: Where would I put that query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Mitch Wheat mentioned, you probably have to separate the DISTINCT into an outer query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM 
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN ... GROUP BY messages.id ORDER BY messages.time DESC
    ) AS inner_q
ORDER BY messages.time DESC
```

But remember, DISTINCT is for distinct records not a single value (someid). messages.time may preventing you from getting what you are after.

Comment: Thanks Brent, is there no way to only return the first result where someid=X?

Comment: Was looking for the "AS inner_q" syntax, thanks for reminding me!